# Xcode Server CI to TestFlight

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, bots, testflight

I've set up an OS X Server and Xcode Service. After this, I've created a Bot for my iOS App.

The Bot is working fine, but I'm asking me now, how could I make the Bot uploading the builds result automatically to TestFlight?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane), in particular [pilot](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/pilot). In it's simplest form once you have everything configured you can call `pilot upload` to upload an ipa in the current directory.